# How would I make this into a function?

Tags: python

I need to turn this in to a function that is shorter I think it should be possible with a for loop but im not sure how to make it alternate then repeat the same move twice. So if someone could show me how to make this a short function that is the goal.

```
t.pencolor("red")
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
t.right(120)
t.pencolor("blue")
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
t.right(120)
t.pencolor("green")
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
t.forward(100)
t.right(120)
```

Comment: Please see [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "*Show me how to solve this coding problem*" [is off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236). You have to [make an honest attempt at the solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), and then ask a specific question about your implementation.

Comment: I think you need to put what is the input and is the output you want so we can get more context.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this because it seems only the color is changing:

```
def someFunction(color,obj): 
    obj.pencolor(color)
    obj.forward(100)
    obj.righobj(120)
    obj.forward(100)
    obj.righobj(120)
    obj.forward(100)
    obj.righobj(120)
    obj.righobj(120)
    return obj

#    Define T 

t = someFunction("red", t)
t = someFunction("blue",t)
t = someFunction("green",t)
```

Comment: While it's good that you know how to solve the problem, it's expected on Stack Overflow not to give direct answers to trivial or homework questions, and especially not without any explanation. Please see [How to ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).